# Javascript Filter HTML Hyperlinks?

Tags: javascript, html, search, filter

I'm trying to implement a simple javascript filter into a HTML page used for a work project. It should allow a user to enter a keyword into an input field, and then everything is removed except hyperlinks having a name matching the keyword.

I found a [jquery example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_filters.asp), however it's not working the way I need.

It successfully filters out the non-matching hyperlinks, however I also want all other elements to be removed as well. I only want a list of matching links, one per line.

Here's my HTML code with my search filter code added: https://jsfiddle.net/0gydcwm6/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".TreeView a").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
```

Edit: I can't restructure the HTML because it is dynamically pulled into the HTML when it's ran. However, I can still add code around the calls which create the list of links. I'm trying to work around what already exists. Also, I'm not well versed in Javascript, so I'm just winging it right now. Also, I'm not married to this jquery code -- I'm just trying to find something that works.

Comment: `.filter()` returns a collection of elements where the callback function returned `true`. Your callback function is missing the `return` statement, and you don't do anything with the result of `.filter()`.

Comment: Just use: `$(".TreeView a").each(function() {`

Comment: Also your anchor elements dont contain the other elements you are probably wanting to hide, you would need to use some other logic to find and hide those elements, or structure your elements differently

Comment: You will have to elaborate more on your issue.

Comment: Your HTML has:
<anchor><img></anchor>
<img>
<img>
<img>
<anchor><img></anchor>
You're going to have to describe which elements are to be hidden and filtered

Comment: @twalow My current code already successfully filters to the entered text for hyperlink. So, after showing the matching <a> hyperlinks, literally all "IMG" and "CATEGORY NAME" text should be removed. Only want the matching results to be shown. CATEGORY NAME (not enclosed in <a> tags are not wanted.

I suppose the IMG could be removed with this: ```$("img").remove();```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

const $input = document.querySelector("#search");
$input.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
 
  const $treeview = document.querySelector(".treeview");
  const typed_txt = e.target.value || '';
  if (typed_txt === ''){
    document.querySelectorAll(".treeview img").forEach(($img) => $img.classList.remove("hide"));
    return;
  }
    
  [...$treeview.children].forEach(($child) => $child.classList.add("hide"));
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".treeview a")].forEach(($anchor) => {
    const match = $anchor.textContent.match(new RegExp("^" + typed_txt, 'i'));
    if (match) $anchor.classList.remove("hide");
    if ($anchor.children)
      [...$anchor.children].forEach(($child) => $child.classList.add("hide"));
  });
 
});


});
```

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="search">

<div class="treeview column">
  <a><img src="example.png">TEXT</a>
  <img src="example.png">
  <a><img src="example.png">TEXTING</a>
  <a><img src="example.png">TEXTED</a>
  <a><img src="example.png">TEXTS</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The example works, but I'm having trouble getting it to work properly with my existing code. Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/8p173j2t/

Comment: I'm somewhat closer to my goal by changing `RegExp("^" + typed_txt, 'i')` to `RegExp(typed_txt, 'i')`, however all of the unwanted elements aren't removed and the text spans horizonally across the page instead of vertically.

Comment: Your example has images and anchors only so this example addresses your example. If you want to remove spans or other elements I'd need to know where they are relative to your example.

Comment: Did you add the css .hide { ... } to your example?

Comment: The example is the jsfiddle link I included in an earlier comment to this answer. It includes the scripts and css provided by you. It is the same code I am using to debug the filter. It should have everything I am currently working with. I know the HTML code isn't formatted well, but that's how it is provided in the source files I'm working in, and I can't change it -- I can only work around it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c2jr8nbu/

Comment: The thing is,. this html is garbage. There's so many things wrong with it. Also you have <br> tags so if I remove those you get your horizontal affect. If you don't hide them then when you hide some of the links then you will multiple <br>s causing a white space gap between elements. Of course it's possible to hack something together but you really need to revaluate your approach before going to these lengths to get this desired effect.

Comment: In addition to all that,. your TEXT are not within tags so you can't really control their visibility because they're randomly inserted into the HTML.

Comment: At this point it would better to parse the anchor tags to make a data object and then make a completely new elements with that data.